# Maze Backtracking Algorithm in C++ DFS?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, depth-first-search, maze

I am new to C++ and I am currently on a project to create a maze that generates out using the DFS algorithm.

I've already successfully managed to generate out a single path, which is for example

```
0 , 0 , 0 , 0,  0
0 , 1 , 1 , S,  0
0 , 1 , 0 , 0,  0
0 , 1 , 0 , 0,  0
0 , D , 0 , 0,  0
0 , 0 , 0 , 0,  0
```

As above,

Source is the initial cell, and 1 is the path that I created based on random neighbor, the thing is, D is "dead end". So, if possible I will like to backtrack to S and start from the other direction. How am I supposed to do that with queue and stack? Can anyone shed some light on this? Thank you so much?

Comment: Questions in Stack Overflow are usually it the form "I have **this code**, and when giving **this input** it produces **this output**, but I was expecting **this output**". Your question is not such so there is little chance that you'll get an answer, and big chance that it will be closed as "too broad".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better if we used basic AI knowledge. Define a set of valid operations for this specific problem, an initial state, a final state and let your program use a `search tree of states` with the defined operations to find the solution.